# how to get the size of data type in python at run time?

Tags: python

Just like we have the `sizeof('data_type')` function in C, is there any function that returns the number of bits or bytes in python?

The function `int.bit_length()` eliminates the zeros before first one.

Comment: Sorry to digress, but I wonder why in the python world do you need to do it in actual program.

Comment: @hspandher:  Well, i wanted to perform binary operation on each bits.

Comment: Well if you really need it you can import sys and use sys.getsizeof(variable)

Comment: @hspandher: I did that. But what did you mean by  _why in the python world do you need to do it in actual program._ ?

Comment: Since abstraction level of python is much higher than c and java, you seldom come across needs to get size of variables and other stuff which is quite common in c like languages.

Comment: @hspandher: okay. But i am very new to python.